# UIView clearColor produce WhiteColor instead of Transparent in IOS5 Xcode4.2

Tags: uiview, ios5, transparency, background-color, xcode4.2

I am facing a very strange issue ever since I updated the Xcode with IOS 5 ...
I can't able to set the background Color of UIView to Transparent ...

here is What I can do :!!

I can set the view to any color , green , blue , red and they are all shown correctly on UIVIEW

```
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];     // Working 100 %
```

I can set a background Image    // it's Working too

```
  [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"abc2010.png"]]]; // Working 100 %


  [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];       // No Error but result is not what I need
```

instead of transparent Background , it is always WHITE ... !!

I'll appreciate the help in figuring out the problem!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just had this same problem. Here's a couple things to do.
Firstly, make sure you set the view so it's not opaque:

```
[self.view setOpaque:NO];
```

Second, set the views layer so it's also clearColor:

```
[self.view.layer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

See if that helps. It fixed my problem, and your's sounds just like mine.
Good luck.